# Shiny Rhino + Shiny.Fluent Reactivity not carrying through modules

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am currently trying to set up a modularized Shiny app using the Appsilon Rhino framework and shiny.fluent package for UI. I am trying to get some reactivity between user selected inputs to feed onto a second pane in the app to show selections of dropdowns without users having to navigate back to the dropdowns to see what they've picked. The data module (user inputs) feeds the selection module (shows selections) which is fed into a layout module which is basically for formatting and UI layout, which feeds the main.R file, feeding the app.R file.

I've tried a few different routes through defining specific reactive elements and using observe() and observeEvent() but can't seem to resolve the selections being displayed based on the user changes. These will need to be monitored constantly as the user could make one selection and then choose a different set of columns in the same session for different results. Code for the various modules below.

---data.R---

```
box::use(
  shiny.fluent[Dropdown.shinyInput, Separator, updateDropdown.shinyInput],
  shiny[moduleServer, NS, div, textOutput],
  janitor[make_clean_names],
  magrittr[`%>%`],
  dplyr[mutate]
)

column_options <- c('column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3')

#' @export
ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  div(
    Separator('fields'),
    Dropdown.shinyInput(
      ns('cols'),
      multiSelect = TRUE,
      value = 'Please select columns to return',
      options = column_options
  ))
}

#' @export
server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    cols_selected <- reactive({
      input$cols})
    
    list(
      cols_selected = cols_selected
    )
  })
}
```

---selection.R---

```
box::use(
  shiny.fluent[GroupedList, DetailsList, Text, Separator],
  shiny[moduleServer, NS, div, textOutput],
  htmlwidgets[JS],
  DBI[dbGetInfo]
)

box::use(
  app/view/data
)

col_headers <- list(
  list(key = 'fields', fieldName = 'fields', name = 'Fields')
)

#' @export
ui <- function(id, cols_selected, fils_selected) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  div(
    Separator('selected fields'),
    DetailsList(items = cols_selected(), columns = col_headers)
  )
}

#' @export
server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    cols_selected <- data$server('data', cols_selected)
  })
}
```

---layout.R---

```
box::use(
  shiny[...],
  shiny.fluent[Stack, fluentPage, Text, Image],
  glue[glue]
)

box::use(
  app/view/selection,
  app/view/data
)

## header UI details ----
header <- tagList(
  div(
    class = "page-title",
    span('App', class = "title"),
    br(),
    span('data', class = "subtitle")
  )
)

## selection pane UI details ----
selection <- selection$ui('selection', cols_selected)

## data pane UI details ----
data <- data$ui('data')

## helper functions ----
# function to create and style overall page
makePage <- function (contents) {
  tagList(
    contents
  )
}

# function to create and style individual cards
makeCard <- function(title, content, size = 12, style = "") {
  div(
    class = glue("card ms-depth-8 ms-sm{size} ms-xl{size}"),
    style = style,
    Stack(
      tokens = list(childrenGap = 5),
      Text(variant = "large", title, block = TRUE),
      content
    )
  )
}

# create base page (without header and footer)
query_page <- makePage(
  div(
    Stack(
      horizontal = T,
      tokens = list(childrenGap = 10),
      makeCard('Choose Data', data, size = 3),
      makeCard('Current selections', selection, size = 3)
    ),
    uiOutput('layout')
  )
)

# function to create layout of header, panes, and footer
layout <- function(mainUI) {
  div(class = 'grid-container',
      div(class = 'header', header),
      div(class = 'main', mainUI)
  )
}

#' @export
ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluentPage(
    layout(query_page)
  )
}

#' @export
server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    cols_selected <- data$server('cols')
    selection$server('selection', cols_selected)
  })
}
```

---main.R---

```
box::use(
  shiny[tagList, moduleServer, NS],
)

# import modules to main app
box::use(
  app/view/layout
)

#' @export
ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    data$ui(ns('data')),
    layout$ui(ns('layout'))
  )
}

#' @export
server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data_module <- callModule(data$server('data'))
    cols_selected <- data_module$cols_selected
    selection$server('selection', cols_selected)
    layout$server('layout')
  })
}
```

---app.R---

```
# Rhino / shinyApp entrypoint. Do not edit.
rhino::app()
```

I have tried observe and obeserveEvent but not working. I think the main issue is stemming from the way I reference the server sides of each module back up to the main.R script but I can't figure out the combination to display the data correctly.

Answer (score -2):

It appears that the issue lies in how the reactive values are being passed between the modules and the main app. To properly handle the reactivity and make sure the selections are displayed correctly, you can make the following changes to your code:

In the data.R module:

You need to modify the server function to return the reactive value cols_selected instead of putting it in a list.

```js
#' @export
server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    cols_selected <- reactive({
      input$cols
    })

    return(cols_selected)
  })
}
```

In the selection.R module:

Make sure to correctly retrieve the reactive value cols_selected from the data.R module by calling the function you created earlier.

```js
server <- function(id, cols_selected) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    return(cols_selected)
  })
}
```

In the main.R module:

There's a minor mistake in how you retrieve the cols_selected reactive value. You should use the data_module object, not the data$server('data') function directly.

```js
#' @export
server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data_module <- callModule(data$server, 'data')
    cols_selected <- data_module()
    selection$server('selection', cols_selected)
    layout$server('layout')
  })
}
```

By making these changes, the reactivity should work correctly, and the selections made by the user will be displayed in the selection module without navigating back to the dropdowns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I will try and implement this. Am I correct in thinking the reactive value called in the UI would then be cols_selected() to retrieve the current value? Also, if anyone does have a more Rhino based approach that would be useful. I don't think the above is incorrect but within the Rhino framework, there is a precedent that callModule() is not used but rather the server variable from a given module is called in through box modules and referenced as a variable using the namespace. Unless I have this incorrect?